# Run a function with another (Non OOP __call)

Tags: php, return-value, call, echo

so I'm pretty much wanting to make my code cleaner, and all of my functions return values, and I would like to avoid using classes/objects for this.

I've experimented with __call() and pretty much copied the way Magento does it, and modified my methods so I can run displayThisFunction() - and it echos the output of thisFunction() - I was wondering if there were any way to do that without __call.

Pretty much how Wordpress does get_this_value() and the_value(), returning and echo'ing respectively, however with wordpress they just have seperate functions for echo'ing, I suppose I could do the same, though I'd like to keep it clean.

Any ideas, is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with echoing the value you are looking for at the end of your function?

Comment: There is no procedural equivalent to `__call` in PHP. But why don't you just use `print(ThisFunction());` instead? That's not much longer (and seems cleaner than the WP approach to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php has no built-in metaprogramming tools. Either you write them all per hand or invent a kind of generator script that creates the stuff for you.

Whether you actually need separate functions just to echo something is another story.